# Start program if and only if a different one has started

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I do the following:

```
start a.exe
wait 5000

if(a.exe has started)
{
    start b.exe
}
```

In other words, `a.exe` is started. If it fails to run for some reason (file not found), then `b.exe` is not executed. Otherwise, `b.exe` is started after five seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the question makes sense now.

I did some tests, and if a.exe does not exist, then a nasty Windows interactive error window pops up, and your batch will not continue until you manually dismiss the error window. (At least that's what happens on my Vista machine) So you probably want to verify a.exe exists prior to trying to start it.

If you know the full path ahead of time, then the test is simple with IF EXIST. But if you don't, then you can search the path with the ~$:PATH modifier to a FOR variable or parameter expansion.

I don't know what happens if a.exe exists but fails to start for some other reason. Perhaps it still pops up with the error window - that would be unfortunate.

I originally thought you needed to use something like TASKLIST to verify that a.exe was running, but now I think you can simply check the errorlevel after the START command.

WAIT is not a standard Windows command, but TIMEOUT is (at least from Vista onward).

```
for %%A in ("a.exe") if "%%~$:pathA" neq "" (
  start a.exe && (
    >nul timeout /t 5
    start b.exe
  )
)
```

Comment: For some reason, `a.exe` does not work when I replace it with `"C:\Program Files\PeerBlock\peerblock.exe"` (that executable file is weird). I ended up rethinking what I wanted and changed it so that it requires user input before starting `b.exe`. But thanks anyways!